# Is the Wearer Asleep/Awake information exposed in the Band SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

Does the Band SDK expose information on whether or not the wearer is currently awake or asleep?

I know this information is provided to the user via the Microsoft Health app in their daily graph, but as a third-party developer can I get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Band SDK does not expose this information.

You can however get the info from the Microsoft Health Cloud API, check out the documentation: https://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI/Explorer#!/Activities/Activities_Get

The sleep data will not be provided in real-time by the Cloud API - as I read the documentation it will be delayed with minimum 1 hour.

Comment: Well thanks for the information! Unfortunate that it's not provided in real time, I guess I'll have to try and figure out another solution that cuts down that hour delay.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that (at least for the Band 1) the device switches Bluetooth off when you put it into sleep tracking mode, presumably because notifications are considered unnecessary while you're asleep!